# Normalize values within a group using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I will need your help with this one. I want to normalize numbers within groups. Say I have this dataset:

```
A  B  C
-------
0  1  3
1  1  0
1  1  2
1  1  4
1  2  1
1  2  1
```

I want to group these rows by A and B, then normalize the values of C *within its group*, i.e. summing up all C's of the group and then dividing each C by that sum. In the above example, I would expect this result:

```
A  B   C
---------
0  1   1            // sum of C's in group is 1, 1/1=1
1  1   0            // sum of C's in group is 6, 0/6=0
1  1  1/3           // ...
1  1  2/3           // ...
1  2  1/2           // sum of C's in group is 2, 1/2=1/2
1  2  1/2           // ...
```

Division by zero can be handled separately. How to do this using SQL (or PSQL, if that helps)? I can think of ways to do this in principle, but I always end up with deeply nested SELECTs, which I want to avoid.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use windowed functions for it:

```
SELECT a,b,
    1.0 * c / CASE WHEN SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY a,b) = 0 THEN 1
                   ELSE SUM(c) OVER(PARTITION BY a,b) END AS c
FROM tab
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bdfd0/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦════╦════════════════════╗
║ a  ║ b  ║         c          ║
╠════╬════╬════════════════════╣
║ 0  ║ 1  ║ 1                  ║
║ 1  ║ 1  ║ 0                  ║
║ 1  ║ 1  ║ 0.3333333333333333 ║
║ 1  ║ 1  ║ 0.6666666666666666 ║
║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 0.5                ║
║ 1  ║ 2  ║ 0.5                ║
║ 2  ║ 2  ║ 0                  ║           -- added for check division by 0
╚════╩════╩════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a derived table to aggregate the values and then `join` the results back to the original table. To avoid division by `0`, a `where` clause has been included. For these `0` sum cases, you might have to include a special condition to select them.

```
select t.a, t.b, 1.0 * t.c/t1.total_c
from tablename t 
join (select a, b, sum(c) as total_c
      from tablename
      group by a, b) t1
on t.a = t1.a and t.b = t1.b
where t1.total_c > 0
```

Comment: Lets test that... hang on :)

Comment: I've upgraded it a bit t.total_c should be `t1.total_c` and Results are 0 for all rows(int division) [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8cd45/4/0) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (a,b,c) as (values
    (0,  1,  3),
    (1,  1,  0),
    (1,  1,  2),
    (1,  1,  4),
    (1,  2,  1),
    (1,  2,  1),
    (2,  2,  0)
)
select
    a, b,
    c::float / coalesce(nullif(sum(c) over(partition by a, b), 0), 1) as normal
from t
;
 a | b |      normal       
---+---+-------------------
 0 | 1 |                 1
 1 | 1 |                 0
 1 | 1 | 0.333333333333333
 1 | 1 | 0.666666666666667
 1 | 2 |               0.5
 1 | 2 |               0.5
 2 | 2 |                 0
```